# Не могу сместить в центр блок

Tags: css, html5, html

Есть блок, нужно что бы он немного отступал от края страницы( справа и слева), но я стыкаюсь с такой проблемой, что margin-right и padding-right  вообще не работают, а margin-left и padding-left лишь немного отступают. Пыталась применить правило как для всего контейнера, так и для блоков "item" отдельно(их мне и нужно сместить к центру)

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
        loop:true,
        margin:10,
        nav:false,
        dots: false,
        responsive:{
            0:{
                items:1
            },
            600:{
                items:3
            },
            1000:{
                items:4
            }
        }
    });
```

```css
.conteiner4{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 95px;  
    padding-bottom: 95px;    
}

.fermashop{
    position: relative; 
}
.maining-ferma{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 48px;
    width: 220px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    padding:35px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}
.buttons div{
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 60px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.buttons div.customPrevBtn{
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
.buttons div.customNextBtn{
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<div class="conteiner4">
        <h2>ЗАКАЖИТЕ СВОЮ МАЙНИНГ-ФЕРМУ!</h2>
          <div class="fermashop"> 
             <div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="maining-ferma">
                      <img src="asseets/img/ferma1.jpg">
                      <p class="description">Mining Rig "ACRONYM" for Ethereum 170 Mh\s</p>
                      <p class="old-price">12 000 грн
                        <span>8 000 грн</span></p>
                      <a class="action" href="#" >ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="maining-ferma">
                      <img src="asseets/img/ferma1.jpg">
                      <p class="description">Mining Rig "ACRONYM" for Ethereum 170 Mh\s</p>
                      <p class="price">12 000 грн</p>
                      <a href="#">ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="maining-ferma">
                      <img src="asseets/img/ferma1.jpg">
                      <p class="description">Mining Rig "ACRONYM" for Ethereum 170 Mh\s</p>
                      <p class="old-price">12 000 грн
                        <span>8 000 грн</span></p>
                      <a class="action" href="#" >ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="maining-ferma">
                      <img src="asseets/img/ferma1.jpg">
                      <p class="description">Mining Rig "ACRONYM" for Ethereum 170 Mh\s</p>
                      <p class="old-price">12 000 грн
                        <span>8 000 грн</span></p>
                      <a class="action" href="#" >ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="maining-ferma">
                      <img src="asseets/img/ferma1.jpg">
                      <p class="description">Mining Rig "ACRONYM" for Ethereum 170 Mh\s</p>
                      <p class="old-price">12 000 грн
                        <span>8 000 грн</span></p>
                      <a class="action" href="#" >ПОДРОБНЕЕ</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="buttons">
                <div class="customPrevBtn"><i class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <div class="customNextBtn"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Добавьте код инициализации owl-carousel

Comment: в смысле в css добавить эти свойства для owl-carousel?

Comment: В смысле  `$(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel(...);`

Comment: я дополнила код, но оно все равно не работает

Answer (score 0):

Если речь о том, что блоки с классом **.maining-ferma** сейчас смещены вправо относительно центра, а Вы хотите это исправить, то вот решение:

- измените у **.maining-ferma** `display: inline-block;` на `display: block;`
- пропишите там же `margin-left: auto;` и `margin-right: auto;`

Тогда блоки будут по центру. Вам останется верхний отступ у первого блока поправить.

```
.maining-ferma{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 48px;
    width: 220px;
    border:1px solid gray;
    padding:35px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
```

Если речь о чем-то другом, то уточните вопрос, пожалуйста: куда и что нужно подвинуть.

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы задаете отступ блокам типа `.item` или `.owl-carousel`, то он смещает блок вправо, но не изменяет его ширину, посмотрите :

```css
.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class=fullwidth>тест</div>
```

*Почему?* Согласно спецификации CSS ширина блока складывается из ширины контента (`width`), значений отступов (`margin`), полей (`padding`) и границ (`border`). Поэтому когда ширина блока задана (`width:100%`), отступы `margin` и `padding` прибавляются к ней справа и слева, расширяя контент за границу страницы.

*Как это исправить?* Есть несколько способов:

1. **Сделайте отступ не у элемента с фиксированной шириной** (`width:100%`), **а у его родителя** (в вашем случае это `.conteiner4`):

```css
.fullwidth {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.container {
  margin: 0 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class=fullwidth>тест</div>
</div>
```

2. **Укажите браузеру, что вы включаете отступ** `padding` **в ширину элемента** `width` c помощью правила [`box-sizing: border-box;`](http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-sizing)

```css
.fullwidth {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 0 100px;
     border: 1px solid red;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class=fullwidth>Тест</div>
```